# HttpContextBase does not contain a definition for 'WebSockets' MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

i've build a rest api (mvc application). i want to rebuild the data loading and call it through a websocket insted of http-post/-get.

i tried:

```
public class WebsocketController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpGet("/ws")]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            using WebSocket webSocket = await
                               HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await Echo(HttpContext, webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

this doenst work, because WebSocket is not defined.

is it possible to add a websocket to an mvc controller?

in the ms-article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it say's add something to the StartUp.cs

but my mvc solution doenst have a startup.cs but rather a void Application_Start in the Global.asax.cs File

Comment: Which .net framework your application targets to.?

Comment: .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: .net 4.7.2 files do not have Startup.cs. also HttpContextBase class in .net 4.7.2 doesn't have Websocket related methods too. The Ms article you read is applicable to .net core which is not the same as .net 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get Websocket's working, i've made a new asp.net core (.net 5.0) project